# Class forcing and progressively closed iteration

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In his published paper ('The Ground Axiom' https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609064), Jonas Reitz gives the definition of progressively closed iteration (definition 92). Informally, an Ord-length  forcing  iteration $\{P_{\alpha}; \dot Q_{\beta}:\alpha, \beta\in Ord\}$ is progressively  closed if  for every  ordinal $\beta$,  on  a  tail  of $\alpha$’s, $P_{\alpha}$ forces  that $\dot Q_{\alpha}$ is <$\beta$-closed.
Suppose that $P$ is a progressively closed iteration. I wuold like to prove that a forcing extension via $P$ is a model of GBC. In order to show that it is enough to prove that $P$ is a tame. Therefore, I need a proof of the following fact:
If $P$ is a progressively closed iteration, than $P$ is a tame.
Are there some references about that?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you check Theorem 95 of Reitz's thesis?

Comment: Note that because of the closure, every $\eta$ has some $\alpha^*$ such that for all $\alpha\geq\alpha^*$, $P_\alpha$ forces that $\dot Q_\alpha$ will not add sets of rank $\eta$. So you are preserving the von Neumann hierarchy.